# XML/ASP: How to get the attribute value for an empty element

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am not used to working with XML at all, so this might seem a stupid question. I have an xml document that will always be formed like this:

```
<lists>
  <list subscriber_count="5048" display_name="" name="GiNsubs" id="705381"/>
</lists>
```

I need to get the value of the 'name' attribute in that empty element 'list'. Since it is empty, nothing I've tried works to get the 'list' element as an object so I can use GetAttribute on it. I've tried GetElementbyTagName, SelectSingleNode, and even FirstChild, but nothing seems to grab the 'list' element as a node. For reference, my code is currently as follows:

```
valid = "No"
Set xmldoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set objLst = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmldoc.async = false
    xmldoc.Load ("{XML document location}")

Set objLst = xmldoc.selectsinglenode("list")
if objLst.GetAttribute("name") = "GiNsubs" then
  valid = "Yes"
end if
```

The error this currently produces is "Object required" on the "GetAttribute" line.

Any help is appreciated.

Oh, and BTW, this XML doc is what comes out of an API, so altering the format of the XML isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked when I tried it

```
<%
valid = "no"

Set xmldoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.validateOnParse = False
'stop 'uncomment to trigger a debugger break here (if you're setup for server-side debugging)
xmldoc.Load "http://domain/subfolder/deleteme.xml" 'add your URL here

xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
Set objLst = xmldoc.selectsinglenode("lists/list")
If objLst.GetAttribute("name") = "GiNsubs" Then
  valid = "Yes"
End If
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>XML XPath Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%=Valid %>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried:  
  
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath" 
Set objLst = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/lists/list").innerText
if objLst.GetAttribute("name") = "GiNsubs" then
  valid = "Yes"
end if  
  
Now it gives the error "Object required: '[object]'" for the line "Set objLst = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/lists/list").innerText".

Comment: What was trhe result when you tried? I am not so sure about the "Set" - try without it. Are you able to debug? Any errors?

Comment: I tried removing the "Set" in the second line you gave - it gave the same VBscript runtime error - "Object required: '[object]'". How would I debug?

Comment: I think most likely your code was not loading the XML on the line `xmldoc.Load ("{XML document location}")`. I have edited my code to show you a tested, working code.

Comment: It must have been the parens around the URL. Weird. Thanks! I'd vote your answer up, but my rep isn't high enough yet. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome. Are you loading XML from URL or local file (I am curious if it's possible to do from local file)?

Comment: Also - you should be able to flag my answer as "The Accepted Answer" without up-voting it.

Comment: it is from a URL. I have 'checked' your answer. Thanks again!